# Detecting two tags in Unity3D for player death

Tags: c#, methods, unity-game-engine, tags

I'm making a classic trap where two walls come together to smash the player. To do this, I've created two separate tags, "Crush" and "Crush1", and assigned one tag to each wall. This is my code on my player class:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Crush" && other.transform.tag == "Crush1")
    {
        Die ();
    }
}
```

I only want the player to be destroyed if both walls are touching the player at the same time. When I remove one of the tags in the parameter, the method works fine (only not how I want it). I'm sure there's a simple workaround here, I'm just not seeing it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Christiopher G is correct in saying you need to store flags as they hit you(and stop hitting you).

I think his is a little bloated though as a new class is not required, your current code is easily expanded to do what you want.

Note: Unity not available to be at the moment so untested.

```
bool wall1 = false;
bool wall2 = false;

void Update()
{
    if( wall1 && wall2 )
    {
        Die();
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Crush")
    {
        wall1 = true;
    }
    else if(other.transform.tag == "Crush1")
    {
        wall2 = true;
    }
}


void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Crush")
    {
        wall1 = false;
    }
    else if(other.transform.tag == "Crush1")
    {
        wall2 = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a single script with the following code and attach it to both your Wall objects:

```
public class WallScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]  //Optional Attribute
    public bool collidedWithPlayer;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            collidedWithPlayer = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            collidedWithPlayer = false;
        }
    }
       //We don't want "collidedwithPlayer" to remain true if either of the walls touches the player before both do so we call "OnCollisionExit" to set it to false.
}
```

Then do the following inside your player script:

```
  private WallScript wall1Script;
  private WallScript wall2Script;

  private void Awake()
  {
      wall1Script = GameObject.Find("Wall1").GetComponent<WallScript>();
      wall2Script = GameObject.Find("Wall2").GetComponent<WallScript>();
  }
```

OR

```
   private WallScript wall1Script;
   private WallScript wall2Script
   public GameObject wall1;
   public GameObject wall2;  //Assign GameObjects in Inspector

   private void Awake()
   {
       wall1Script = wall1.GetComponent<WallScript>();
       wall2Script = wall2.GetComponent<WallScript>();
   }
```

Then inside the same script:

```
  private void Update()
  {
      if(wall1Script.collidedWithPlayer && wall2Script.collidedWithPlayer)
      {
         //Do Something here
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You know, when the player touch two walls.
function `OnCollisionEnter` will be execute twice.
the first time, `other.transform.tag == "Crush"` is true.
the second time, `other.transform.tag == "Crush1"` is true.
in `OnCollisionEnter`, `other` have only one tag.
It will never be true that `tag == tag1 && tag == tag2` if `tag1 != tag2`